# Displaying Youtube thumbnails in my ruby app from Youtube Data API : what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thumbnails, youtube-data-api

I've been working on this app I made called **youtube cancer free** for a week now and I'm having issues with thumbnails. What I'm trying to do is displaying channel title + video title + video thumbnail when sending youtube API requests. So far the latter seems not to work and I don't really know why.
This is a sample of what the result looks like when doing a research:

```
    JRE Clips
Joe Rogan on France's Anti-Macron Riots
#<Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::ThumbnailDetails:0x00007fa7c862c790>
```

For the record this is what my controller looks like:

```
    class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
def index
    youtube_data_api = YoutubeDataApi.new.client
    @result, @errors = youtube_data_api.list_searches 'snippet', q: 
'youtube france -cyprien -fortnite -gotaga -gamemixtreize -bodytime - 
farod -andy -telefoot -konbini -topito -inthepanda -vdbuzz -mickalow - 
sandrea', max_results: '50'
end
end
```

and what my view looks like:

```
    <div>
<% @result.items.each do |video| %>
<div>
<%= video.snippet.channel_title %>
</div>  
<div>
<%= video.snippet.title %>
</div>  
<div>
<%= video.snippet.thumbnails %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Could anyone please tell me what's my mistake and what could be done to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer myself lol 
`@result, @errors = youtube_data_api.list_videos 'snippet, id', chart: 'mostPopular', region_code: 'FR', max_results: '50'`

You can lock this topic now if you want.